# Data extraction from a text file using bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I am looking for a bash script. In a text file I have data like:

```
+------+------
| Id   | User | 
+------+------+
| 8192 | root | 
| 8194 | root |
| 8202 | root |
| 8245 | root | 
| 8434 | root |  
| 8754 | root | 
| 8761 | root | 
| 8762 | root | 
| 8764 | root | 
| 8771 | root | 
+------+------+
```

I want to extract the data like this:

```
8192,8194,8202,8245,8434,8754,8761,8762,8764
```

I mean, I need the first field containing numbers, but not the last one, and all the numbers extracted should be separated by commas (`,`).

Could  somebody help me to get it ?

Comment: Where does this come from? SQL? If so why not SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT {fields} ) FROM ...

Comment: @Rinzwind yes it is a SQL output. No AFAIK its not from a table. All these are MYSQL sleeping PID which I have to kill.

Comment: Is this still needed due to [Kill Sleeping Process in MySQL](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425600/kill-sleeping-process-in-mysql) ? :D

Comment: Yes @Wilf , there I can list the data but I can not put it in format because sometimes I may get 100 Connections. 100 ID putting in format by separating with comma , bash can do that very easily rather than me.

Comment: almost All answers are excellent , which one I have to accept thats big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a script for such a simple thing. You can use `awk`:

```
awk '$2 ~ "^[0-9][0-9]*$" { print $2 }' file.txt | head -n -1 | awk '{print}' ORS=',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Some explanations:

- `awk '$2 ~ "^[0-9][0-9]*$" { print $2 }' file.txt` - print from the `file.txt` only the fields which are numbers.
- `head -n -1` - remove last line / last number.
- `awk '{print}' ORS=','` - concatenate all lines in one single line, each number separated by `,`.
- `sed 's/,$/\n/'` - replace last `,` with a newline character.

Or, shorter:

```
awk '$2 ~ "^[0-9][0-9]*$" { print $2 }' ORS=',' file.txt | sed 's/,[0-9]*,$/\n/'
```

Comment: My brother , Thanks for answering.+1 , How about If i do have IP's because due to security reasons I have not gave you any IP's.IP's are third field.

Comment: @rajagenupula Just replace `{ print $2 }` with `{ print $6 }` and `sed 's/,[0-9]*,$/\n/'` with `sed 's/,[0-9.]*,$/\n/'`

Answer (score 4):

The most shortest way I can find:

```
echo `sed 's/[^0-9]//g' your_file` | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Result is:

```
8192,8194,8202,8245,8434,8754,8761,8762,8764,8771
```

`[^0-9]` - means everything but numericals

`s/[^0-9]//g` - removes everything but numericals

Substitute `your_file` with path to your file

---

For you finally task, with `kill` command. **Be carefully when using this line, it will kill every PID in list**:

```
for pid in `sed 's/[^0-9]//g' your_file | grep -v '^$'`; do kill -9 $pid;done
```

Before run previous line, you may want to run this line:

```
for pid in `sed 's/[^0-9]//g' your_file | grep -v '^$'`; do echo "kill -9 $pid";done
```

It will show something like this:

```
kill -9 8192
kill -9 8194
kill -9 8202
kill -9 8245
kill -9 8434
kill -9 8754
kill -9 8761
kill -9 8762
kill -9 8764
kill -9 8771
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: you are awesome man , thanks for that such short one. but actually in connection files sometimes I may get IP's also which also numerical. so how you're command can separate them from process IP's ? Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't you be sending `SIGTERM`s first?

Comment: I cannot send SIGTERM to a MySQL database to terminate its sleeping process

Comment: @rajagenupula What about `SIGINT` and `SIGHUP`?

Comment: @BlacklightShining thanks for your interest. I am not sure that they can help me but I will look at them one more time and I will let you know for sure. Thank you again

Comment: Programs should be sent signals they can actually handle, in order to give them a chance to clean up. I don't know anything about MySQL, but this seems especially true for database-related processes. [If `SIGKILL` is the only way to get a program to exit, uninstall it and find an alternative.](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#uuk9letter)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an one liner for your purpose,

```bsh
sed 's/[^0-9]//g' file.txt| xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

or

```bsh
sed 's/[+|IdUserroot\-]*//g' file.txt | xargs | sed 's/ /,/g'
```

Output:

```
8192,8194,8202,8245,8434,8754,8761,8762,8764,8771
```

**Explanation**

`man sed`

```
s/regexp/replacement/
          Attempt  to  match  regexp  against the pattern space.  If successful, replace that
          portion matched with replacement.  The replacement may contain the special  charac‐
          ter  & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special
          escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding matching sub-expressions in the
          regexp.

g     Copy/append hold space to pattern space.
```

Regular expression<sup>[[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)</sup>

```
[^ ]    Matches a single character that is not contained within the brackets.
For example, [^abc] matches any character other than "a", "b", or "c". [^0-9]
matches any single character that is not a number from "0" to "9".
```

Hence using `sed` I have replaced everything with space. Next `xargs` put them in a line separated by space,

```
$ sed 's/[^0-9]//g' file.txt| xargs
8192 8194 8202 8245 8434 8754 8761 8762 8764 8771
```

At last step I have replaced all the spaces with `,` using `sed`

Comment: Thanks for answering +1 , I like to have some explanation because in future it perhaps helps someone to understood what this command can do. :)

Comment: @rajagenupula take a look at the edit. Plz let me know if it need any further explanation :)

Comment: If i am checking with more number of fields ( they have sensitive information) , its not helping. but with given information you are right. I am not saying that this is wrong but I am saying that its not much accurate for exact extract. Thank you again for answering.

Answer (score 1):

where the text is in an `input` file in the same directory, and result is given in  `output` file.

```
cat ./input | sed -e 's/+------+------+//g' | sed -e 's/| Id   | User |//g' | sed -e 's/ | root |//g' | tr -d "\n" | sed -e 's/| /,/g' | sed -e 's/ ,/,/g' | sed -e 's/ ,/,/g' > output
```

When I did it your example I got:

```
+------+------,8192,8194,8202,8245,8434,8754,8761,8762,8764,8771
```

That may because the top line of your example was missing a `+` - there may be a few other errors...

Then I think you just need to add `sudo /mysql_rms/bin/mysqladmin -S /mysql_rms/var/mysql_rms.sock -p kill` at the beginning

---

Or, in what is hopefully a slight improvement on what Radu suggested (also based on  the above input):

```
cat ./input | sed 's/[+-]*//g' | sed 's/ | root |//g' | tr -d "\n" | sed 's/| /,/g' | sed 's/ ,/,/g' | sed 's/ ,/,/g' | sed 's/^,//' | sed 's/,[0-9]* $/\n/' | sed 's/Id//g' | sed 's/,User,,//g' | sed 's/ //g' > output
```

Then, based on you Q&A [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425600/kill-sleeping-process-in-mysql), you should be able to run:

```
sudo /mysql_rms/bin/mysqladmin -S /mysql_rms/var/mysql_rms.sock -p kill $(cat ./output)
```

although you may want to check whether it is the right command with this first:

```
echo "sudo /mysql_rms/bin/mysqladmin -S /mysql_rms/var/mysql_rms.sock -p kill $(cat ./output)"
```

Comment: Better to use `sed -e 's/[+-]*//g'` instead of `sed -e 's/+------+------+//g'`.

Comment: how about fixing that small unwanted thing ? thanks for answering and effort :)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu - Better? - I would spend more time on learning this sort of thing, but I need more of a certain entity called 'time'

Comment: And `cat` is not necessary. Look at the `man sed`; `sed` can take as argument an input file (and this is normal, since `sed` is an stream editor).

Comment: @Wilf But you have a lot of time, and you spend it on askubuntu like me an others :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you needed. Some other answers failed to remove the last part.

```
sed -n 's/.*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*/\1/p' file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g; s/\(.*\),\(.*\)$/\1/g'
```

A small example,

```
$ (echo '| Id   | User |'; echo '| 8192 | root |'; echo '| 8194 | root |'; echo '| 8771 | root |') | sed -n 's+.*\([0-9]\{4\}\).*+\1+p' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g; s/\(.*\),\(.*\)$/\1/g'
8192,8194
```