# kill sleeping process in mysql?

Tags: mysql, process

I have a MySQL database, which is very often filling with sleep process and I have to open my workbench and then have to kill them to free connections & then it will work fine.

Is there any way I can do that from command line?

Comment: A detailed blog :http://sforsuresh.in/how-to-delete-sleeping-processes-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

To list all sleeping process in your database

```
sudo /mysql_rms/bin/mysqladmin -S /mysql_rms/var/mysql_rms.sock -p processlist
```

Here you will get list of data , among that list the first field is pid.

To Kill all of them

```
sudo /mysql_rms/bin/mysqladmin -S /mysql_rms/var/mysql_rms.sock -p kill <id1>,<id2>
```

Id's are nothing but pid which was taken above. You can kill one after one or you can kill all of them at a time by appending them one after one by separating with comma (,).